# error while opening docker quick start terminal can someone have a look

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, dock

DockerToolbox in windows OS

Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\Alamdar Hussaini.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\Alamdar Hussaini.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to create a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'default' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Alamdar Hussaini.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstall completely VirtualBox,
delete any vbox* file in C:\Windows\system32\drivers\,
delete any vbox* folders in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services,
restart machine to be at safe side, 
reinstall virtualbox.

This should resolve the issue.